# DBRefs support in Mongodb java driver 4.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

It is found that Database References can be achieved on MongoDB Java driver version 4.0 Here is the link below
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/

But I couldn't find a relevant tutorial or guide which achieves the same for version 4.0. I am a newbie to the Mongo world. Can anyone figure out what am I missing here?

Comment: [com.mongodb.DBRef](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/DBRef.html)  is the representation of a database reference.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to make use of this class? @prasad_ I  couldn't find any tutorials on the internet.  Even the link for tutorials are also enough for me

Comment: What are you trying to do?